# Force subquery result to be scanned instead of existing one

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Can I somehow force mysql to do a full scan on the subquery result instead of the existing table?

Let's say I've got a query:

```
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_b WHERE ...)
```

If I'm sure that the subquery returns ~10 results, while table_a has thousands, can I somehow force table_a records to be looked up, and table_b result to be scanned? Mysql insists (according to `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_a...`) to do ALL on table_a and index lookup on table_b.

Comment: Please include the indexes that you have on the tables and the actual explain plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead you can add index on field `id` and try `INNER JOIN`:

```
DELETE a
FROM table_a a 
     INNER JOIN table_b b
         ON a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: yes definitely you can and its faster than subquery approach. :)

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of `where someColumn in( ... )` compared to a proper join is HORRIBLE.

Use an inner join on the two tables instead.

Avoid `in` and other clauses where the indexes cannot be used.